# angularjs same directive (outside click) for multiple elements

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

So I have 2 elements with the same directive: (coffeescript)

```
myApp.directive "clickOutside", ["$document", ($document) ->
    restrict: "A"
    link: (scope, elem, attr, ctrl) ->
        elem.bind "click", (e) ->
            e.stopPropagation()
        $document.bind "click", ->
            scope.$apply attr.clickOutside
]
```

and the HTML:

```
<div class="filter-box" click-outside="showFilterList=false">
    <div class="filter-title" ng-click="showFilterList=!showFilterList;">Open</div>
    <ul class="filter-list" ng-class="{show:datePickerModel.showFilterList}">
        <li></li>
        ...
        ...
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="filter-box" click-outside="showFilterList=false">
    <div class="filter-title" ng-click="showFilterList=!showFilterList;">Open</div>
    <ul class="filter-list" ng-class="{show:datePickerModel.showFilterList}">
        <li></li>
        ...
        ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have 2 DIV's that click on the filter-title will change the showFilterList to true and by that the filter-list gets the 'show' class. clicking outside the element will set the showFilterList to false and filter-list is hidden again. Everything is working fine expect for one scenario: clicking on the first element filter-title and show the filter-list. clicking on the second element filter-title will show itself filter-list but won't set to false the first element that was already clicked.

How can I do it so each directive will have it's own scope when triggered?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried giving a scope in the directive, i.e. `scope: yes`?

Comment: I tried now and still won't work

Answer (score 0):

Florian's answer is correct for creating an isolated scope for the directive see: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive (it should be `scope: true` according to the docs).

From your code I'd guess there is something else in your code that may be causing it as you have `show:datePickerModel.showFilterList` whereas everywhere else you have `showFilterList`. Probably the problem is that showFilterList is being created in the parent scope by something else.

Try recreate your problem in a [codepen](http://codepen.io) or a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), it gives us some code to help you with and often I've found that redoing my problem in a clean environment can lead me to find the issue anyway.